# ASP.NET OData query returns properties with empty values for virtual properties in code first models

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, odata

I'm currently building a ASP.NET OData service which uses code first with EF5. When I do the query of a entity, it is returned as JSON along with empty values for the related entities.

I want the related entities attributes not to be included in the returned JSON for the entity query unless 'Include' is explicitly mentioned.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What does your request URI look like? Can you show the sample response? I suspect you are not using $expand in your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable lazy loading by setting the related members as virtual